# How to connect and fix old Seagate bricked HDD

Tags: hard-drive, windows-11

I have an old IDE HDD which I can no longer connect to my PC because the cables are different (SATA). Are there also options to connect the HDD to my notebook? Maybe through a suitable docking station? In addition, the HDD appears to work, but it seems to be bricked (HDD = from my dad). Is it even possible to get this (bricked) HDD to work?
My notebook: dell xps 15, with windows 11 as OS.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: "it seems to be bricked" How exactly did you come to that conclusion? If it's defective then there's no point in wasting money with adapter, obviously. But if it still works (unlikely but possible) there are USB adapter cables, USB enclosures and yes, slot-in "docking stations". Good luck finding one still supporting PATA.

Comment: Note that a decent modern HDD/SSD of the same capacity is not much more expensive than the adapter.

Comment: did you connect a power supply?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a carrier with an IDE connection. I use a Sabrent dual IDE and Sata for this.

Put the drive in the Carrier, plug it into a USB port, plug in the AC supply and attempt to read the drive.

You may need to try a recovery utility like Recuva (cc cleaner) to recover data.

If there is important data on the drive, consider a local recovery agency before doing anything yourself.

The drive is too old for any permanent use.

Comment: Sabrent. But Sabrenet would be a much better name.

Comment: Fixed it   ......

Comment: What kind of AC supply can I buy for this hdd?

Comment: A carrier you get like the Sabrent comes with an AC supply. A good carrier will come with a supply.  Any kind of direct cable connection to the computer would need a power connector in the computer. I do not advise a direct connection

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/AGPtek-Drive-Adapter-Converter-External/dp/B00BIE996S/ref=sr_1_4?keywords=Ide+To+Usb+Adapter&qid=1636498016&sr=8-4

Comment: Read the one-star reviews of the product linked above.